# Is it okay to store ws clients in an array in NodeJS?

Tags: arrays, node.js, websocket, persistent-storage

I'm using the [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) library so WebSockets implementation.
In this, to broadcast, the GitHub page has a [sample code](https://github.com/websockets/ws#broadcast-example) that does a `forEach` on `wss.clients` and sends data to everyone of the clients.

But, I don't like the idea of storing clients, an important set of data, in an array that can be destroyed by a simple server restart.

Is there a way to store the clients somewhere more persistent, like Redis.
So, I store the metadata of `clients` in Redis and create the `client` on the go from Redis as required.

Or is this Redis a bad approach and arrays are just good enough?

Any reference on the matter would be wonderful.

Comment: The WebSocket library doesn't make any assumptions about whether you need persistent user state. `wss.clients` is just a list of which clients (not users - if I log on to StackOverflow on two devices, I'll have two clients but I'm still only one user) are connected right this second, so it makes sense that it empties when the server goes down. If you want to create some kind of mapping between clients and users, you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: So, it's okay that it's just an array. I see. Makes more sense now.

Comment: The library socket.io has a redis adapter. What's that for? They say it's for scaling horizontally. Would that be a problem for me? @JoeClay

Comment: The Redis database, in that case, is in fact managing clients rather than users - this allows you to load balance between multiple servers, and stay online if one of your servers goes down :)

Comment: Can I achieve that with arrays at all? Or should I find a way to use Redis..?

Comment: For example, StackOverflow's notifications are most likely running on clustered WebSocket servers - if I log on on two devices, they could both be connected to different servers, but I'd still get notifications on both because the list of connections is (probably, I'm just guessing) held on a shared database.

Comment: Oh. Load Balance. Oh. So we shift clients from the dead server to an alive one

Comment: I still dunno how to store clients in a shared database. Any help?

Comment: I would not recommend to use an array, tried it, causes some delays on response, use redis for storing clients info or better use object database e.g. mongodb, firebase for perfomance

Comment: @JuliverGalleto interesting, socket io however seems highly bloated, are you familiar with any examples of ws redis session management stuff, i couldnt find anything on google after 2 hours for ws redis manager

Answer (score 2):

I would advice you to follow the approach in https://medium.com/@willrigsbee/how-to-keep-track-of-clients-with-websockets-1a018c23bbfc It is better to create an object with key/value pair so that the key will be the userId and value will be the socket.